# What does it mean for a random variable to be bigger than another?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I came across the following question while self-studying:

$$\text{Show that if } X \le Y \text{ then } E(X) \le E(Y)$$

Does it mean, for instance, that every value of $Y$ is bigger than every value of $X$?

Comment: It means $P(X\le Y)=1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That is only a consequence. It means that $X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)$ for every $\omega$ in sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: @drhab That's a very non-probabilistic way of thinking; one doesn't care what happens in the whole sample space, just about what happens in a complement of a probability zero event.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Nevertheless that is what it means, and not something less like $X\leq Y$ a.s.

Comment: @drhab A probabilist would never go beyond saying an event holds almost surely.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown There are situations in which a probabilist starts with $X\leq Y$ a.s., reforms it to $X'\leq Y'$ (where $X=X',Y=Y'$ a.s.), then (in the more convenient model) does the job, and then translates back again to $X,Y$. So your "never" does not hold.

Comment: Yes, the domain of $X$ precedes that of $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with the same underlying probability space $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf{P}\rangle$ then note that $X$ and $Y$ are measurable functions $\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

In this context $X\leq Y$ then stands for:$$\forall\omega\in\Omega\left[X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)\right]$$

A consequence of that is:$$\mathsf{P}(X\leq Y)=1$$or in words: $X\leq Y$ *almost surely*.

Another consequence - requiring that for both the expectation exists - is:$$\mathsf EX\leq\mathsf EY$$as is mentioned in your question.